# Access and change the state array element in main React App from grandchild

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I apologize for the headline of this question, but I tried to explain the problem as much as I could in one line.

Our school assignment required us to create a (sort of) Tic Tac Toe game but in a certain way. Instead of creating nine different Box elements from the main `App`, we were required to create `Row` class and `Box` class, so the main App will have three `Row` class children and each `Row` class will have three `Box` children.

Now the problem I encountered is how to change the main App state array at a particular element that corresponds to that exact Box component.

I am a beginner and I apologize in advance if I am not seeing something too obvious. If you have any questions, please do ask, I'll be more than happy to explain this as much as I can. Thank you!

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { render } from 'react-dom';
    
    class App extends Component {
      constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
          0 : ['-','-','-'],
          1 : ['-','-','-'],
          2 : ['-','-','-']
        };
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
      }
      handleClick(){
        // if that particular element is '-' change from '-' to 'X'
        // else if it is 'X' change to 'O'
        // else change to 'X'
      }
      render() {
    
        const rows = []
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          rows.push(<Row key = {i} msg = {this.state[i]} handleClick = {this.handleClick}/>)
        }
    
        return (
          <div>
            <div>
              <h1>Tic Tac Toe</h1>
            </div>
            <div id = 'main'>
              {rows}
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
    }
    class Row extends Component{
    
      render() {
        const boxes = []
        for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
          boxes.push(<Box key = {i} msg = {this.props.msg[i]} handleClick = {this.props.handleClick}/>)
        }
        return (
          <div className = 'row'>
            {boxes}
          </div>
        )
      }
    
    }
    
    class Box extends Component{
    
      render() {
        return (
          <div className = 'box' onClick = {this.props.handleClick}>
            <p>{this.props.msg}</p>
          </div>
        )
      }
    
    }
    render(<App />, document.querySelector('#root'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have organized your components well. You need to handle player switching after each click and updating the values in the game board.

1. Add another state variable called `player` (it can just be a boolean as this is a two-player game)

```
this.state = {
      0: ["-", "-", "-"],
      1: ["-", "-", "-"],
      2: ["-", "-", "-"],
      player: true
    };
```

2. You can pass row and col index to `handleClick` function like below.

```
  handleClick(row, col) {
    // set the corresponding value (using row and colum index) in the game borad
    this.setState(
      {
        [row]: this.state[row].map((val, colId) =>
          colId === col ? (this.state.player ? "X" : "O") : val
        )
      },
      () => {
        // switch the player (toggle the player boolean value)
        this.setState({ player: !this.state.player });
      }
    );
  }
```

3. Pass the `row` and `col` ids from the click handler in `Box` component.

```
       <Box
          ...
          ...
          handleClick={() => {
            this.props.handleClick(this.props.row, i);
          }}
        />
```

[Code Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/happy-cannon-hdicu?file=/src/App.js)

NOTE: when you develop further to avoid changing the same Box by clicking, you can keep an object to store more info like `{ value: "-", used: false }` instead of `"-"` as values.

Comment: @Milos Popovic, check this out !!

Comment: THANK YOU so much for this answer. It is such a smart solution! I've shared it with my cohort mates and they were all stunned. Great approach, very understandable code. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Building off of @Amila Senadheera's answer, you could also add a check in the handleClick function to ensure that a player can't overwrite another player's move.  Something along the lines of:

```js
handleClick(row, col) {
    // set the corresponding value (using row and colum index) in the game board
    if(this.state[row][col] !== '-') {
      return // Don't allow the player to overwrite an already-marked square.
    }
    this.setState(
      {
        [row]: this.state[row].map((val, colId) =>
          colId === col ? (this.state.player ? "X" : "O") : val
        )
      },
      () => {
        // switch the player (toggle the player boolean value)
        this.setState({ player: !this.state.player });
      }
    );
  }
```

And if you want to add a check for victory, there's some useful discussion here: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/24764/tic-tac-toe-victory-check.

Comment: Nice, this extra functionality is so useful! I will definitely use it in my code! Will be happy to read more about it in the article you posted. Thank you @Alex!

Answer (score 1):

You could define parameters for handleClick like

```
type T = 1 | 2 | 3;
function handleClick(row: T, col: T) {
  const newRow = [ ...this.state[row] ];
  this.sign = this.sign === "O" ? "X" : "O";
  newRow[col] = this.sign;
  this.setState({...this.state, [row]: newRow});
}
```

and then you need new props for Box:

```
for (let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  boxes.push(
    <Box 
      row={props.row}
      col={i}
      key={i} 
      msg={this.props.msg[i]} 
      handleClick={this.props.handleClick}/>
  )
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Maziar! This is great and really helpful! Thank you!